# Internal predicates evaluate/2 and evaluate2/2

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

The execution profiler of SICStus Prolog 4.5.1 reported the following to me:

```
| ?- print_profile.
       insns   try/retry      called        name
----------------------------------------------------------------
                          ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
                             1769156/8845768    prolog:evaluate/2
                             7076612/8845768    prolog:evaluate2/2
    76073600     7076616     8845768        prolog:evaluate2/2
                             7076612/8845768    prolog:evaluate2/2
----------------------------------------------------------------
                          ...
```

Out of curiosity: what is `evaluate2/2` and how can I find out which parts of Prolog code call it?

(My best guess is this: `evaluate/2` and `evaluate2/2` evaluate arithmetic expressions which are still variable when some `(is)/2` goals are compiled...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The `prolog:evaluate/2` and `prolog:evaluate2/2` predicates are helpers used when the expression cannot be evaluated directly in C (or in assembly with the JIT compiler). Typically because a (sub-) expression was a variable at compile time and then a compound term at runtime.

They are also called when interpreted code (asserted or consulted) evaluates arithmetic expressions with `is/2` and other predicates.

There is no way to know these things except asking the SICStus developers (like me).

Comment: Very helpful! Apparently, a significant part of these calls in `library(clpz)` come from convenience predicates/grammars like `X is E --> { X is E }.` which makes some code a bit more readable, albeit at some runtime costs... now it's time to figure out the other (easily avoidable) uses of `evaluate/2`!